# What is the difference between Aurora Mysql 5.7.x and Aurora 2.x.x

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds, aws, aurora

I have an RDS instance with Aurora Mysql 5.7.12 and I noticed that there are other versions of Aurora Mysql 5.7, but I don't understand what is the difference between them.

Some of the version listed are:

- Aurora (MySQL)-5.7.12   <- The one that I have.
- Aurora (MySQL 5.7)-2.03.2
- Aurora (MySQL 5.7)-2.03.3
- Aurora (MySQL 5.7)-2.03.4
- Aurora (MySQL 5.7)-2.04.1
- Etc...

I attach an image of the AWS Console:
[image: different versions of aurora mysql 5.7]
I want to chose the right version (the one that have most bug fixes in order to have better stability in my system).

Answer (score 0):

They're differences in the minor/patch versions of Aurora.

If you spin up an instance of **Aurora (MySQL)-5.7.12**, then run:

```
SELECT @@aurora_version; -- Returns 2.02.5
```

It's essentially the first version of MySQL 5.7 compatible Aurora.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.html